FLUTTER: My Icon adds an automatic margin
I'm trying to align my view so that all the widgets have the same margin that looks uniform but Icon is generating an automatic margin for me, I don't want to use an app bar for this.
This is my view:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterView({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double marginHorizontal = size.width * 0.09;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: marginHorizontal),
                child: appBar
              ),
              SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.02,),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: marginHorizontal),
                child: description
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }

  Widget get appBar => Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        iconSize: 40.0,
        onPressed: (){}, 
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.white,)
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        width: 10.0,
      ),
      Text(
        'Registro',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      )
    ],
  );

  Widget get description => Text(
    'Completa los siguientes datos',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
  );

}

I'm trying to get my Row to align completely to the left of my screen but it seems the Icon is automatically adding a margin.

Indeed, when removing the IconButton, the rest of the widgets align correctly
I tried this and it didn't work
IconButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        iconSize: 40.0,
        onPressed: (){}, 
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.white,)
      ),

Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: IconButton(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          iconSize: 40.0,
          onPressed: (){}, 
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.white,)
        ),
      ),

I'm almost sure that the problem is in the Icon Widget since when trying to implement this with a GestureDetector the problem persists.

try
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),

Still the same :(

Set visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact to remove unnecessary padding IconButton

About the Icon widget itself, it's always visible as a square widget, that's why it has size property instead of width & height, this is the requirement of icon design.
But arrow_back_ios_new icon doesn't have width = height in terms of design, that's the problem
The solution here is maybe you need a custom arrow icon (through icon font) to generate your real square arrow by yourself to serve your expectation. Or you need a trick like your appBar has less margin left than the others

This answer clarified my doubts, how do you see the size of the wdigets at runtime?

You can use this https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector

To remove padding around the IconButton, try also to add constraints and padding to IconButton properties and padding again to ButtonStyle properties.
Below an example:
IconButton(
constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
iconSize: 20,
style: ButtonStyle(
 padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.zero),
 ),
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
onPressed: () {}
icon: Icon(
 Icons.filter_alt_off,
 ),
),


Still not eliminating that annoying margin on the left

remove the margin from the container containing the appbar :)

If I remove the margin that the container has, it is still not aligned with the rest of the column widgets. I could remove it and leave it like that but now I'm kind of obsessed with this invisible margin and I would like to know how to remove it or why this happens.

You can use Padding differently to fix this problem (even though this is not a clean solution):
class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double marginHorizontal = size.width * 0.09;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              getAppBar(marginHorizontal),
              SizedBox(
                height: size.height * 0.02,
              ),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: marginHorizontal),
                  child: description)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getAppBar(final double marginHorizontal) {
    const double iconSize = 40.0;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: marginHorizontal - iconSize * 0.2 - 10,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              iconSize: iconSize,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),
          Text(
            'Registro',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get description => Text(
        'Completa los siguientes datos',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
      );
}

